# Using i18next & react-i18next packages for language localization.When I reload the page getting error:Text content does not match server-rendered-html

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next, react-i18next

I'm implementing language localization in my nextjs project. I'm using i18next and react-i18next packages. switching between languages is working and the content also changes to the language that is switched. But the problem is when i reload any page after switching it from the default language it shows an error like this:
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.
Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "English" Client: "英語"

i have done server-side rendering for the language selection. in my _app.js seems that doesn't
here is some of my code base.
any help to solve this error will be appreciated.

this is my i18n.js file.

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

import enTranslation from './locales/en.json';
import jaTranslation from './locales/ja.json';

i18n
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    resources: {
      en: {
        translation: enTranslation,
      },
      ja: {
        translation: jaTranslation,
      },
    },
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true, // Set to false in production
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // React already escapes variables
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

this is my header.js where select language is made avilable here

```
    Header,
    Group,
    UnstyledButton,
    Divider,
    Center,
    Box,
    Burger,
    Drawer,
    ScrollArea,
    rem,
    Avatar,
    Menu,
  } from '@mantine/core';
import { useDisclosure } from '@mantine/hooks';
import { IconChevronDown, IconPlayerPause,} from '@tabler/icons-react';
import { useStyles } from './Style';
import { IconSettings } from '@tabler/icons-react';
import { IconSwitchHorizontal } from '@tabler/icons-react';
import { IconLogout } from '@tabler/icons-react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
 
const user = { name: "John Doe", image: "profile.jpg" };
const tabs = ["Home", "About", "Contact"];

  export const  HeaderMenu=(user,tabs)=> {
    const [drawerOpened, { toggle: toggleDrawer, close: closeDrawer }] = useDisclosure(false);
    const [linksOpened, { toggle: toggleLinks }] = useDisclosure(false);
    const { classes, theme ,cx} = useStyles();
    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
    const router = useRouter();
    const [userMenuOpened, setUserMenuOpened] = useState(false);
    const handleLogout = () => {
      console.log('first')
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      router.push('/login');
    };
    useEffect(()=>{
      i18n.on('languageChanged',()=>{
        setUserMenuOpened(false)
      })
    },[i18n])
    const handleLanguageChange = (event) => {
      const selectedLanguage = event.target.value;
      i18n.changeLanguage(selectedLanguage);
    };
    return (
      <Box>
        <Header height={60} px="md">
          <Group position="apart" sx={{ height: '100%' }}>
          <img src="/icon.png" alt="logo" />  
            <Menu
            width={260}
            position="bottom-end"
            transitionProps={{ transition: 'pop-top-right' }}
            onClose={() => setUserMenuOpened(false)}
            onOpen={() => setUserMenuOpened(true)}
            withinPortal
          >
            <div>
            <select
              value={i18n.language}
              onChange={handleLanguageChange}
              data-testid="language-selector"
            >
              <option value="en">{i18n.t('header.language.english')}</option>
              <option value="ja">{i18n.t('header.language.japanese')}</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <Menu.Target>
              <UnstyledButton
                className={cx(classes.user, { [classes.userActive]: userMenuOpened })}
              >
                <Group spacing={7}>
                  <Avatar src={user.image} alt={user.name} radius="xl" size={40} />
                  {/* <Text weight={500} size="sm" sx={{ lineHeight: 1 }} mr={3}>
                    {user.name}
                  </Text> */}
                  <IconChevronDown size={rem(12)} stroke={1.5} />
                </Group>
              </UnstyledButton>
            </Menu.Target>
            <Menu.Dropdown>            
              <Menu.Item icon={<IconSettings size="18" stroke={1.5} />}>
              User Profile
              </Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item icon={<IconSwitchHorizontal size="18" stroke={1.5} />}>
                Admin Area 
              </Menu.Item>

              <Menu.Item icon={<IconPlayerPause size="18" stroke={1.5} />}>
                Change Password
              </Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item color="red" icon={<IconLogout size="18" stroke={1.5} />} onClick={() => handleLogout()}>
                Log Out
              </Menu.Item>
            </Menu.Dropdown>
          </Menu>
            <Burger opened={drawerOpened} onClick={toggleDrawer} className={classes.hiddenDesktop} />
          </Group>
        </Header>
  
        <Drawer
          opened={drawerOpened}
          onClose={closeDrawer}
          size="100%"
          padding="md"
          title="Navigation"
          className={classes.hiddenDesktop}
          zIndex={1000000}
        >
          <ScrollArea h={`calc(100vh - ${rem(60)})`} mx="-md">
            <Divider my="sm" color={theme.colorScheme === 'dark' ? 'dark.5' : 'gray.1'} />
  
            <a href="#" className={classes.link}>
              Home
            </a>
            <UnstyledButton className={classes.link} onClick={toggleLinks}>
              <Center inline>
                <Box component="span" mr={5}>
                  Features
                </Box>
                <IconChevronDown size={16} color={theme.fn.primaryColor()} />
              </Center>
            </UnstyledButton>
            <a href="#" className={classes.link}>
              Learn
            </a>
            <a href="#" className={classes.link}>
              Academy
            </a>
  
            <Divider my="sm" color={theme.colorScheme === 'dark' ? 'dark.5' : 'gray.1'} />
  
            <Group position="center" grow pb="xl" px="md">
        
            </Group>
          </ScrollArea>
        </Drawer>
      </Box>
    );
  }
```

this is my _app.js

```
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import i18n from '../i18n';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { MantineProvider } from '@mantine/core';
import { Notifications } from '@mantine/notifications';
import {useEffect} from 'react'

 function App(props) {
  const { Component, pageProps, userLanguage } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(userLanguage); // Change the language on the client side as well
  }, [userLanguage]);

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Charitybit</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
      </Head>
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
      <MantineProvider>
        <Notifications autoClose={4000} position="top-right" />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </MantineProvider>
      </I18nextProvider>
    </>
  );
}
export async function getServerSideProps(appContext) {
  const { req } = appContext;
  const userLanguage = req.language || 'en'; // Get the current language from the request object or use the default language

  await i18n.changeLanguage(userLanguage); // Change the language to the user's preferred language

  let appProps = {};
  if (typeof App.getServerSideProps === 'function') {
    appProps = await App.getServerSideProps(appContext);
  }

  return { ...appProps, userLanguage };
}
export default App;
```

en.json

```
    "header.language": "Language",
    "header.language.english": "English",
    "header.language.japanese": "Japanese",
    "content.addOrder": "Add Order."
  }
```

ja.json

```
    "header.language": "言語",
    "header.language.english": "英語",
    "header.language.japanese": "日本語",
    "content.addOrder": "注文の追加"
  }
```